# Using rasdial command in Jenkins

Tags: c#, jenkins

I want to use rasdial as build step in Jenkins and I receive the following error:"Remote Access error 623 - The system could not find the phone book entry for this connection."
When I run the same command in console it works. Do you know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you Trying with the same user?
if you are using hudson slave check also the slave service user